# How to update Ave street type to Avenue in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to replace 'Ave' in street address to 'Avenue' using update statement with replace function.

Data before update

```
3237 Vineville Ave
2680 Montpelier Ave
```

using below query:

```
begin tran 

update [dbo].[UsystblCustomer]
set bAddress = REPLACE(bAddress, 'Ave', 'Avenue')
Where bAddress like '%Ave%'
```

Data after update results like :

```
3237 Vineville Avenuenue
2680 Montpelier Avenuenue
```

But I want it to be

```
3237 Vineville Avenue
2680 Montpelier Avenue
```

Is there anything missing or wrong in the update statement ?

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The update statement is correct. This happened because you run the update twice.

First update: find 'Ave' and replaced it on 'Avenue'

Second update: find 'Ave' in '**Ave**nue' and replaced it on 'Avenue'  then as a result we got ‘**Avenue**nue’

I hope this query will solve the problem:

```
update [dbo].[UsystblCustomer]
set bAddress = REPLACE(bAddress , 'Avenuenue', 'Avenue')
Where bAddress like '%Avenuenue%'
```

Comment: May be a space character can be used to distinguish if "Ave" is used within a longer string which does not mean avenue

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. `where bAddress like '%[ ]Ave%'`

Comment: @Eralper. Yes you are correct. I did found some address like 1470 beavers Road got updated to 1470 beavenuers road

Comment: I ran below two query and the result was perfect                            update [dbo].[UsystblCustomer]
set bAddress = REPLACE(bAddress, 'Avenue', 'Ave')
Where bAddress like '%Ave%'


update [dbo].[UsystblCustomer]
set bAddress = REPLACE(bAddress, 'Ave', 'Avenue')
Where bAddress like '%[ ]Ave%'

Comment: @MegaTron  .. I highly appreciate your help

Comment: @Eralper .. Appreciated